# Regarding xmin of logical slot

Tags: database, postgresql, logical-replication, pglogical

There is xmin parameter in replication slot.I saw this value is empty in case of logical replication.From this it is clear that logical slots does not help in preventing vacuum process of dead tuples required by select queries on standby.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 0):

Logical replication slots have `catalog_xmin`, because logical decoding needs to be able to access old, deleted information from the catalog tables. For example, if you truncated or renamed a table, and logical decoding has to process a WAL record from before the truncation or renaming, it still has to be able to access the state of the catalog as it was when the WAL record was written.

`catalog_xmin` will hold back `VACUUM` progress just as well as `xmin`.

Comment: Thank you @Laurenz Albe.I understood that catalog_xmin protects required old catalog tuples from VACUUM process.But in logical replication if I examine the values of logical slot,I found the value of xmin is empty all time and catalog_xmin is not empty.My question how does logical slot protects required xmin from VACUUM process?

Comment: By virtue of `catalog_xmin`.

Comment: Protecting catalog tuples with catalog_xmin will indirectly protect xmin also even xmin field is empty in logical slots,is that right?I thought both catalog_xmin and xmin are different because catalog_xmin protects system catalog tuples and xmin protects normal dead tuples in user table.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, they have the same effect on `VACUUM`.

Comment: Assume current catalog_xmin of slot is 100,now i got new transaction 101 which  inserts one row to a user's table,I observed that  after decoding transaction 101 the value of catalog_xmin=101,why catalog_xmin is incremented,it should be increment only when a transaction effects system catalog tuples right,Is this right understanding.?If so then why the value incremented.

Comment: `catalog_xmin = 101` means that we cannot remove anything newer than transaction 101 from the catalog, because those dead rows might still be needed for logical decoding. PostgreSQL doesn't track if there are any dead rows in the catalog or not (that is, if you performed any DDL or not).

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329101/regarding-hot-standby-feedback-parameter
In above question's comment's section you agreed that replication slot will not prevent VACUUM...can you refer it and explain in detail,Thank You.

Comment: can you give little more deatiled explanation why catalog_xmin updated to 101 for simple insert statement.?

Comment: In the linked question, I did *not* say that a replication slot will or will not prevent `VACUUM`. I don't understand what information is still missing. Perhaps you need to read the code - that's where everything is explained in minute detail.